# How do you properly loop through file path and add the files to a comboBox with VS? C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, combobox

Here is my code:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     string[] f = directory.GetFiles(path);
     foreach (string file in f)
     {
          comboBox1.Items.Add(file);
     }
}
```

However, this does nothing. Well, nothing visible at least. When I click the drop down arrow to view the comboBox, it doesn't show the contents of the file.
Is there something I'm leaving out?

Thank you.

Comment: Where did you program that it would show the contents of the file?

Comment: A) Why are you trying to populate it in the `SelectedIndexChanged` event? How is that event going to fire before there is data in it? B) There is an `AddRange` method which you might want to consider

Comment: `comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged` will not be triggered when you haven't got any items. _"chicken and egg problem"_ You should fill the combobox on the _(anything like)_ `Loaded` event

Comment: You need to break it down into two tasks: 1) read files and populate the combo box and 2) when selection is changed, display the contents of the file.

Comment: Are there files in 'path'? Does the value of 'path' refer to an existing accessible Directory?

Comment: Yes, path is an existing file path.

Comment: @Jeffrey Jordan, is any update? Please check if my answer works for you.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following code to use `Form_Load` event to add the files to the combobox.

```
 public Form1()
        {
            this.Load += Form1_Load;
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        string path = "E:\\Video";
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string[] f = Directory.GetFiles(path);
            foreach (string file in f)
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add(file);
            }
        }
```